# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') at users.js:18

Tags: javascript, authentication, fetch

I am trying to create a login form whereby the users data is fetched via a fetch request and is checked with the following javascript code:

```
fetch('./login.php', {
    method: 'GET'
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then(res => {
    let user = []
        for (let data of res){
            user.push({
                email: "'"+data.email+"'",
                password : "'"+data.password+"'"
            })
        }

    let button = document.querySelector('.btn btn-danger submit');

    function login(){
        let email = document.getElementById('useremail').value;
        let password = document.getElementById('userpassword').value;
        for(i=0; i < user.length; i++){
            if(email == user[i].email && password == user[i].password){
                window.location = "home.html";
            }
        }
    }
    
    button.onclick =  login();
})
```

Whenever I check the console it shows the error in the title.
Is there something wrong with how I am trying to go about this?

Here is my HTML code for the form (using bootstrap):

```
<form action="" id="loginform">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="useremail" class="form-label">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="useremail" aria-describedby="Email" name="useremail" required>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="userpassword" class="form-label">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userpassword" aria-describedby="Password" name="userpassword" required>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger submit" type="submit">Login</button>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <a href="register.html" class="text-decoration-none text-decoration-underline text-dark fst-italic">Don't have an account? Register Here.</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let button = document.querySelector('.btn btn-danger submit');` is wrong. It'll select a `submit` class inside `btn-danger` inside a `btn` class.

You need `let button = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-danger.submit');`. Or in my opinion, add an `id` to the button and use that.

Also, I am pretty sure `button.onclick = login();` would be just `button.onclick = login;` as you don't need to execute the function immediately, but bind the function to the `onclick`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The error disappeared but unfortunately, the login function doesn't seem to be working and still keeps me on the same page instead of moving me to home.html. But you did answer my question and the error did disappear, so thank you!